# Как избавится от булевой переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for A in range(1,120):
    a=True
    for m in range(1000):
        for n in range(1000):
            if ((2*m+3*n>43) or (m<A) or (n<=A))==False:
                a=False
    if a==True:
            print(A)
```

Comment: вынести в функцию и возвращаться сразу True\False

Comment: Не пойму каким образом это можно сделать, если тут идет перебор миллиона значений для каждой А из 120, не возвращать же мне миллион True?

Comment: @StupNum если у вас хоть раз выполнится условие в цикле, то уже не нужно перебирать дальше. Если условие в цикле выполняется, то делаете return, если не выполняется, то не делаете

Answer (score 5):

Функция `foo` вернет значение на первом совпадении. В лучщем случае нам не надо будет ждать для всех 1 млн значений.

```
def foo() -> bool:
    for m in range(1000):
        for n in range(1000):
            if not (2*m + 3*n > 43 or m < A or n <= A):
                return False
    return True

for A in range(1, 120):
    if foo():
        print(A)
```

Comment: `if A == False:` → `if not A:` ?)

Answer (score 4):

```py
for A in range(1,120):
    if all((2*m+3*n>43) or (m<A) or (n<=A))
           for m in range(1000)
           for n in range(1000)):
        print(A)
```

В отличие от вашего кода, `all` остановится на первом несовпадении

Answer (score 4):

1 шаг: можно заменить внутренние два цикла на одинарный цикл с помощью [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
for m in range(1000):
    for n in range(1000):
        ...
```

меняется на

```
for m, n in combinations(range(1000), 2):
   ...
```

Если бы количество итераций `range` было разным, то можно было бы заменить на [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
for m, n in product(range(1000), range(200)):
   ...
```

2 шаг: при выполнении условия в цикле делаем `break` (если условие хоть раз выполнилось, нет смысла идти дальше), к циклу добавляем `else` (который выполнится только если не было `break`), в нем делаем `print`.

Полный код:

```
from itertools import combinations

for A in range(1, 120):
    for m, n in combinations(range(1000), 2):
        if not ((2*m+3*n>43) or (m<A) or (n<=A)):
            break
    else:
        print(A)
```

Первый шаг нужен потому, что `break` в Python выходит только из одного цикла.

Идея взята из обсуждения к этой статье: [Breaking out of two loops](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201608/breaking_out_of_two_loops.html#comment_15041).